# Does cloning a Bitlocker drive change its decryption key?

Tags: bitlocker

A windows 10 is installed on a SSD on a laptop, the drive is Bitlocker encrypted.

Now the laptop is broken.

The SSD will be cloned onto a new and bigger SSD. Afterwards the Bitlocker has to be decrypted.

Question:
Does the bitlocker key ID change and therefore the 48 letter decryption key?

Comment: Did this laptop have a TPM?  If you are a making a 1:1 copy of the disk, the BitLocker configuration would not be changed, but if you were using a TPM it means you need the recovery key to decrypt the drive.

Comment: It is a company Lenovo laptop in company domain, so... perhaps it has TPM? But does this Bitlocker key change?

Comment: I already address that question in my comment.  In order for me to submit an answer, you need to provide the information required to answer it, without that information my answer will be invalid.

Comment: @apraetor - If you have your own question you should submit a question instead of asking a question in a comment